# Saving commit changes in shell

Tags: git, shell, smartgit

I have a Git repository `ssh://git@x/y/`, where I need to commit a file using Smartgit Shell. I've simply written the two lines below.

```
git add README
git commit
```

This opens a commit window (see below), where I simply uncomment the file `README`. However, how do I save the commit-file? Currently I'm stuck in this window.

[image]

I suppose I have to use some key combination?

Comment: It's unclear to me what you want to achieve. What do you mean with saving, in an editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The editor that launches is vim, which may be a bit confusing to people not used to it. It has an editing mode that you can start by pressing <kbd>A</kbd> and you can leave it again by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

Once you are out of editing mode, you can enter <kbd>:wq</kbd> or just <kbd>:x</kbd> to save and exit the editor. This will make Git use the message for the commit.

Note that you shouldn’t uncomment those lines. Everything below the “Please enter …” text is just a hint (lines starting with `#` are ignored) for you so you know what you are about to commit (what files were changed in the commit, which weren’t). Instead, you should just enter a message *above* it and then save/exit the editor.

If you don’t want to bother with vim, you can also configure Git to use a different editor instead. There is also the [gitpad](https://github.com/github/gitpad) project that allows you to use the default Windows notepad (or others) as a commit editor.

Comment: What should I enter above it? Do I need to enter anything in this editor to complete the commit?

Comment: @felbo you need to press `i`, then type the commit message on the top line, then press `Esc`, then `:wq`. Also, you can commit without opening a text editor. Just do `git commit -m "commit message"`.

Comment: And what is the commit message if I simply want to commit the file README?

Comment: @felbo The commit message is the text you attach to the commit that explains what you did. Please read a tutorial, e.g. the [Git Book](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).

Answer (score 3):

If your git editor is vim, which is most likely, you need to press <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then type `:wq`.

Comment: Thanks. Was that information shown somewhere? That key combination is not in any way obvious.

Comment: @felbo: Well `vi` makes use of command mode and edit mode. In command mode (press `esc`) you can run `:help` for a list of commands.